# Check if a process is running with shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to make a script to see if the process chromium is running.
The script should check every 10 seconds if the process is running and it must end when it finds it 10 times.
Here is my code.

```
#!/bin/bash

count=0

while true; do
    sleep 10s
    isthere=`$(top) | grep -w chromium`
    if [ $isthere -ne 0 ]; then
        count=$((count+1))
    fi
    if [ $count -eq 10 ]; then
        echo "You found the process 10 times"
        exit 50
    fi
done
```

I'm having no output whatsoever. I don't know if I'm using the command `top` properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, your usage of `top` command is incorrect. You try to invoke it from the shell script and it hangs as a result.

You should use `top` command with some specific options. I suggest you use it with `-b` option which corresponds to the "batch" mode and `-n` options which is for the number of iterations `top` produces its output. For more information check `man top`.

Also the test for `isthere` variable should be amended (we check it for non-emptyness).

The resulting script which works is something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

count=0

while true; do
    sleep 10s
    isthere=`top -b -n 1 | grep -w chromium`
    if [ -n $isthere ]; then
        count=$((count+1))
    fi
    if [ $count -eq 10 ]; then
        echo "You found the process 10 times"
        exit 50
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `pgrep`.

```
$ if pgrep ksh >/dev/null; then echo "ksh is running"; fi
ksh is running
```

In a loop:

```
i=0
while (( i < 10 )); do
  if pgrep ksh >/dev/null; then
    (( ++i ))
  fi
  sleep 10
done
```

Substitute `ksh` with the tool of your choice.